# How to store specific part of youtube URL - VB

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a textbox. In the textbox the user will insert a youtube link such as: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJNR2EpS0jw' . However I only need this part of the URL 'youtube.com/watch?v=IJNR2EpS0jw' . So my question is how can I write a code to store the selected part of the URL I need. I think it needs to start of like this:
        Dim specificurl As String
        specificurl = TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("youtube.com")
Regards

Comment: Please show what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know how to go about it but I thought something like this :         Dim specificurl As String
        specificurl = TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("youtube.com")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the String.Replace method to strip the `https://www.` out of the string.

```
Dim URLString As String = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=..."
URLString = URLString.Replace("https://www.", "")
URLString = URLString.Replace("http://www.", "")
```

This will get you the value you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks alot worked perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

If there's any chance your input may have capital letters (unlikely since this is a URL), you'd need to use `Regex` to do the replacement (this would also let you do both HTTP and HTTPS in one line):

```
Dim newValue As String = Regex.Replace(input, "^https*://", String.Empty,
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```